# How can I disable Google https search in Firefox 17.0.1?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has a search bar. In new versions of Firefox it opens Google in SSL mode. How can I disable SSL mode and put it in normal http mode?

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your JavaScript console (Firefox button -> Web Developer -> Web console) and type this in:
   `window.external.AddSearchProvider("http://mycroft.mozdev.org/installos.php.html/14909/google.xml");`
2. Press Enter and a message box will appear asking you to add the search engine. Press Add.
3. Change the search provider from within your search bar to Google US. Now all searches made by the search bar will be HTTP searches.

Comment: It is still HTTPS

Comment: Are you sure? Did you change the search provider? HTTP for me.